# Running validations getops in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to figure out checking validation if they did not pass option -d option give error. Did the user gave me right arguments if not give error. Did user provide any arguments if not give error. Basically validation and it gives out errors . User has to put argument -d with option u- or -p but not both

```
do_p=0   # initialize variables
do_u=0
random_file=””

  while getopts "d:uph?" option; do
          case $option in
           d)
               random_file=$OPTARG
               ;;
           u)
               do_u=1
               ;;
           p)
               do_p=1
               ;;
           h)
                Help
                exit;;

           \?)  echo "Error: Invalid option"
                exit;;
        esac
  done

**#Validations**

 # Does the file exist
  if [[ ! -f device_file ]]; then
      echo "Error: The file $device_file does not exist."
        exit 1
    fi
```

I was checking online  one of the ways would be  if statement
by  #Validation would this work??

```
  if [ ! -d "$device_file" ]; then
  echo "pass in argument"
  exit 0
  fi
  
  if [ d"${OPTARG:0:1}" == "d-" ]; then
  echo "did not pass in option -U or -P"
  exit 0
```

Comment: `[ d"${OPTARG:0:1}" == "d-" ]` is **exactly** identical to `[ "${OPTARG:0:1}" == "-" ]`; the `d` doesn't buy you anything. (They're also both buggy with common `/bin/sh` implementations: The only POSIX-standardized comparison operator is `=`, not `==`).

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly, you don't exit 0 for error, you exit >=1, and you write error messages to standard error.

You're also testing -d which is a directory, but calling it a "device file" in the script, which sounds wrong, but I'll let you figure that out.

The first statement looks vaguely right, but I would prefer this:

```
[ "$device_file" ] || { echo "missing -d device_file argument" 1>&2 ; exit 1 ; }
[ -d "$device_file" ] || { echo "$device_file is not a directory" 1>&2 ; exit 2 ; }
```

For the 3rd thing you have there, it doesn't look right to me, but I can't be botherered to dig around and figure out what it does. If it were me, I wouldn't initialise do_provision and do_unprovision, I'd just set them to true if found. Then I'd write:

```
[ "$do_provision" -o "$do_unprovision" ] || { echo "must provide -u or -p" 1>&2 ; exit 3 ; }
```

Comment: `-o` is marked obsolescent in the POSIX `test` standard. Modern best practice is `{ [ "$do_provision" ] || [ "$do_unprovision" ]; } || { echo "Must provide -u or -p" >&2; exit 3; }`, though personally I'd use `if` for better clarity to readers.

Comment: ...if you want to do things the bash way instead of the POSIX way, use `[[ $do_provision || $do_unprovision ]]` instead, which isn't subject to the class of bug that led to `-o`'s withdrawal (because `[[` has parser support, it can tell if words were quoted, so the data-vs-syntax ambiguity that led to deprecation of `-o` doesn't exist). It's silly to write code with legacy POSIX syntax if you think "nobody cares about POSIX".

Comment: They are not "withdrawing the feature". Some boffins in POSIX who are irrelevant, thought they'd take a shot at killing the feature by half heartedly putting it in the standard yet marking it obsolescent, and their attempt failed because those folks are irrelevant.

Comment: I don't know what case you refer to that there is ambiguity between data and code, it's certainly not this simple case. The test command is full of situations like that, shell scripting is bit of a black art, but it is what it is. Making the test command itself obsolete wouldn't be a terrible idea, but here we are. For all intents and purposes, GNU [whatever unix command] is the defacto standard for better or worse. Your GNU bash solution to the problem doesn't help you escape GNU, although at least test has rich history of working, your bashsolution would leave many old hands scratching heads

Comment: Okay, here's an example: `[ -f = -a -o -a ]` -- should this mean `[ "-f" = "-a" ] || [ "-a" ]`? Because there exist versions of bash that barf on it, including the release that still ships with MacOS today. Which means `[ "$a" = "$b" -o "$c" ]` as a whole is unreliable.

Comment: (try it on a current Mac: `/bin/bash -c '[ -f = -a -o -a ]'` throws `/bin/bash: line 0: [: argument expected` on OS X 12.5.1)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Kernigan's UNIX programming environment from 1983 mentions a case like this.  test doesn't work well when the data looks like an argument. The work around is usually something like put "X" or some such in front of the variables... test X-f = X-a -o X-a != ""   .... now if there was any danger of the variables containing dash, I could do that or use one of the more elegant workarounds. But when I know that's not a possibility, it's harmless.

Comment: *test doesn't work well when data looks like an argument* -- exactly what I meant by "data-vs-syntax" ambiguity. Is it really better to need to know what your program's data will look like before you can be assured of correct execution than to use bash builtins _or_ stick to the unambiguous subset of `test` syntax? And if we accept that there's an _ambiguous_ subset of test syntax, is it really good practice to showcase that subset in a teaching resource?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In this case, the "data" passed to test is wholly contained within the script, it doesn't come from externally. You make it sound like the only bits passed to test that are "data" are the bits you conveniently deem so. But what happens when people put flags to test in variables that then become data?  test "$a" "$b" "$c" ... now what? If the concern is that unexpected things could come in from externally and populate $a $b and $c, then who knows what test does at this point.

Comment: ...I'm having trouble untangling the thinking behind your argument above. You _acknowledge_ that data can come in outside a script's source. You _acknowledge_ that the contents of that data can lead to `test`'s behavior being ambiguous. And then... you leap from there to a conclusion that it's perfectly acceptable to use `test` in ways where that ambiguity leads to potentially surprising results. I find myself completely unable to follow that leap. `test "$a" "$b" "$c"` is clearly unacceptable if one wants reliable behavior, but my point above is that so is `test "$a" = "$b" -o "$c"`

Comment: ...thus, my argument is that rather than try to figure out case-by-case which uses of syntax involving `-o` and `-a` are unambiguous and thus acceptable, it's far safer and saner (and easier to teach) to just write the whole thing off, and switch to combining multiple, smaller `test` invocations with `&&` and `||`.

Comment: Re: "when I know it's not a possibility" -- needing to do case-by-case analysis means more work (and more opportunity for mistakes) for you as an author, and for the reviewers vetting your code; and it means _much_ more background that needs to be taught to juniors before they can work at your level. Why do things that provide opportunity for mistakes when you could instead follow practices that don't allow that room? Save your thinking/analysis time for more important uses, and sidestep the potential for error altogether.

Comment: (someone who's changing a variable to be parameterized rather than hardcoded shouldn't need to think "do I need to rewrite all the conditionals operating on this variable to use unambiguous syntax now?"; relying on things-that-are-currently-true to decide that it's safe to write otherwise-fragile code makes changes to that code later more likely to break things).